# If $(f_1,...,f_n)\in \text{Maps}(X,k)$ are linearly independent, then there exist $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ s.t. $(f_i(x_j))$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is an assertion that seems correct to me (source: Algebraic Groups and Algebraic geometry  by Geck; cf proof of 2.4.3, although its an elementary statement) but I can't see an immediate proof.

**If** $f_1,...,f_n\in \text{Maps}(X,k)$ **are linearly independent** (in the $k-$vector space of maps from a set $X$ to a field $k$), **then there exists elements** $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ **such that** $(f_i(x_j))$ **is an invertible matrix**.

Here is an idea : Let $V:=\operatorname{Span}(f_1,...,f_n)$. Considering the functionals $\pi_x=f\mapsto f(x)\colon k^X\to k$ (for $x\in X$) can we show that $\operatorname{Span}(\pi_x|_V\mid x\in X)=V^*$?

Then we can use the fact that if $V$ is any finite dimensional vector space with $b_1,...,b_m$ as a basis and $g_1,...,g_m$ is a basis of $V^*$ then $(g_i(b_j))$ is invertible (this follows from $\cap \ker(g_j)=0$).

A proof of the above fact or any other elementary proof of the statement (in bold) would do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the composite map $F := (f_1, \ldots, f_n) : X \to k^n$.  Then we first see that $\{ F(x) \mid x \in X \}$ must span all of $k^n$; otherwise, there would be some nonzero functional $\varphi \in (k^n)^*$ whose kernel contains the span, and taking the coefficients of $\varphi$ would give a contradiction to the linear independence of $f_1, \ldots, f_n$.

So now, since $k^n$ has dimension $n$, there are $n$ elements $F(x_1), \ldots, F(x_n)$ of this spanning set which form a basis of $k^n$.  That implies directly that the matrix $(f_i(x_j))$ is invertible.

Comment: Ah...that was simple and slick...thanks...Also discovered this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2661385/492061